# debugging jquery mobile on iphone chrome browser

Tags: iphone, debugging, jquery-mobile

I have a simple login page in a mobile site that should be reached the very first time the user arrives at the site. It used to work before (I used to test it by clearing cookies on the phone.) Now it has stopped working and I am not sure how to debug it. Here are the symptoms

1. It works on safari running on iphone
2. It works on ipad chrome
3. It works on desktop chrome (and ripple iphone simulator)
4. But it **does not work on chrome browser** running on iphone

Any thoughts on how I can go about debugging this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had done a chrome upgrade two days back. I did not reboot the iphone ater that. I switched the phone off and on and it worked.